# RadComboBox.ClientID is being changed in CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik

I have ASP.NET `webforms` application which uses `telerik` controls.

While working with `RadComboBox`, ClientID is being changed in `CodeBehind.cs`

I am moving control position from a `div` to `asp:Panel`.

Similar action on different page doesnot changes ClientID. Only difference between these pages are this page is, it has master page and other doesnot.

**Image before ClientID is changed**.
[image: Image before ClientID is changed]

**Image after ClientID is changed**.
[image: Image after ClientID is changed]

I donot know, What is actually causing the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I am using ClientID in CodeBehind and aspx page to create Javascript function and both have different value for ClientID.

**JS function from CodeBehind:**
[image]

**JS function from ASPX:**
[image]

**JS function from CodeBehind on framesource(rendered):**
[image]

**JS function from ASPX on framesource(rendered):**
[image]

Comment: Yes. Using a master page changes the ClLientID's. But that should not be a problem unless you hard-code those id's in javascript oid. If you really want you can set them to `ClientIDMode="Static"` (not reccomended).

Comment: @VDWWD ClientID changes seems to be only on CodeBehind not on aspx, which is causing issue.
 I have updated question also with more details